# how to use nobs in sas so that it can be used to find percentage frequency

Tags: sas

I have imported one datafile. It has 246 observations. By using nobs how can I replace 246 in the last sentence of my code to find percentage?

```
proc import datafile='G:\Data file\Dec 2014.csv'                                                                  
out=out.datafile 
dbms=csv 
replace;

*SUMMARY TABLE IS MADE;                                                                                                 
proc summary data = out.datafile missing;                                                                                                               
class AGE sentiment;  *age, sentiment are two columns in datafile;                                                                                                                                   
var ;                                                                                                                                                    
output out = out.summ_age ;                                                                                                   
run;

*SORTING SUMMARY TABLE BY AGE;                                                                                                                           
proc sort data = out.summ_age;                                                                                                                           
by age;                                                                                                                                                  
run;                                                                                                                                                     

*TRANSPOSING THE SORTED DATA WITH AGE AS OBS SENTIMENT VALUES AS COLUMNS;                                                                                
PROC transpose data = out.summ_age out = out.hsi_age;                                                                                                    
by age;                                                                                                                                                  
id sentiment;                                                                                                                                            
var count;                                                                                                                                               
run;

data out.hsi_age;                                                                                                                                        
set out.hsi_age;
tot = d+s+i;
PERCENTAGE=round((tot/246)*100,0.01); /*PERCENTAGE PER GROUP*/                                                                                            
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to the number of observations in a dataset into a macro variable then you can put this count into a macro variable - as in your case:

```
proc sql ;
  select count(*) 
  into :N
  from out.datafile  ;
quit ;
```

You can then call this in your final step:

```
data out.hsi_age;                                                                                                                                        
set out.hsi_age;
tot = d+s+i;
PERCENTAGE=round((tot/&N.)*100,0.01); /*PERCENTAGE PER GROUP*/                                                                                            
run;
```

Comment: Actually my different datafiles are giving two different outputs. Some files are giving me 200% while adding up all the percentage and some are giving 100%. I think it is issue with my datafiles . Thats y I try to work with nobs.

Comment: I updated my answer - still very similar but you just use `count()` instead of `sum()` in proc SQL

Comment: Now it is working. But now I got into another trouble. 
Even though I have 196 observations in csv file, while importing into sas it becomes 200+ observations with excess observations. And those excess observations are dots in datatable. Why so? How can we remove them?

Comment: without seeing the csv file can't say for sure - although I would guess your `infile` statement needs fixing if you're getting more observations than are in your csv file. Try having a read through http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi26/p009-26.pdf

Comment: i used if statement and now its working properly

if age=. then delete;

Comment: The `types` statement is needed if you want to avoid getting the extra rows. They're not coming from the CSV, they're coming from `proc summary`, at least if you replicated the code accurately here.

Answer (score 1):

So, the reason you have missings and 200% and all that is your `PROC SUMMARY` generates more data than you want.  You want the crossing of age and sentiment, but you actually get:

- age
- sentiment
- age*sentiment
- all data (Grand total)

You need to ask for what you actually want.  This did give us a little bonus: you don't have to go look for the NOBS, you can actually get it from one of these extra lines (the age-not-crossed-with-sentiment).

Assuming you have `sashelp.class`, and replacing sentiment with sex, you can do it like this:

```
proc summary data = sashelp.class missing;                                                                                                               
class AGE sex;  *sex replaces sentiment here;      
types sex age*sex;  *we want the grand total for each separate sex, and crossed with age;
var ;                                                                                                                                                    
output out = summ_age ;                                                                                                   
run;

*SORTING SUMMARY TABLE BY AGE;                                                                                                                           
proc sort data = summ_age;                                                                                                                           by age;                                                                                                                                                  
run;                                                                                                                                                     

*TRANSPOSING THE SORTED DATA WITH AGE AS OBS SEX VALUES AS COLUMNS;                                                                                
PROC transpose data = summ_age out = hsi_age;                                                                                                    
by age;                                                                                                                                                  
id sex;                                                                                                                                            
var _freq_;                                                                                                                                               
run;

data hsi_age;                                                                                                                                        
set hsi_age;
retain grand_tot;
if _n_=1 then grand_tot=M+F;  *the first row has the null age values, grand total by sex;
else do;
    tot = sum(M,F);
    PERCENTAGE=round((tot/grand_tot)*100,0.01); /*PERCENTAGE PER GROUP*/                                                                                            
    output;
end;
run;
```

You could also generate what you're looking for via `proc tabulate`, but this works just as well.

Comment: Note this doesn't exactly do `nobs`, but it's not clear to me that `nobs` is actually correct - nobs here is the number of observations in the summarized dataset, not the original dataset.  If you want it to add to 100%, you need the original dataset's count.  My method above gets to that using the summary-produced rows, though it's certainly not needed (just convenient).

Comment: Very elegant - this is a better approach to getting your desired output than the accepted 'fix' to your original code

Answer (score 1):

The NOBS option creates the regular variable that you can access in the same way as any other variable within the given data step (the only difference is that this variable is never output to the target data sets). I guess that what you are willing to do can be achieved in the following way:

```
data out.hsi_age;                                                                                                                                        
    set out.hsi_age nobs=my_nobs_var;
    tot = d+s+i;
    PERCENTAGE=round((tot/my_nobs_var)*100,0.01); /*PERCENTAGE PER GROUP*/                                                                                       
run;
```

Comment: If `nobs` is actually desired this is the way to go - doesn't require a second pass through the data.